# How to upload an image to cloudinary

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary

I want to upload an image to cloudinary form my NodeJS api, i have my model, in this model i have a field called image, this field is type string and here I want to save the url that a receive as response of cloudinary.

Here is my model.js

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CursoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Curso', CursoSchema);
```

And my controller.js, here is where I have to save the url, I tried with the method of cloudinary docs.

```
var imageFile = req.files.image;
cloudinary.uploader.upload(imageFile.path, function(result){
  if (result.url) { res.status(200).send({url: result.url});
  }else {
    console.log('Error uploading to cloudinary');
 }
});
```

but I just uploaded images. Here is my controller.js

```
'use strict';

const Curso = require('../models/curso');
const config = require('../config');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: 'something',
  api_key: 'somthingelse',
  api_secret: 'andotherthing'
})

function saveCurso(req, res) {
  let curso = new Curso();
  let params = req.body;
  curso.name =  params.name;
  curso.description = params.description;
  //How to get the image and upload it to cloudinary

  curso.save((err, cursoSaved)=>{
    if(err){return res.status(500).send({message:'Error'});}
    if(!cursoSaved) return res.status(404).send({message: 'Empty'});
    return res.status(200).send({curso: cursoSaved});
  });
}

module.exports = {
  saveCurso,
}
```

And my routes.js file:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const api = express.Router();
const cursoController = require('../controllers/curso');

api.post('/curso', cursoController.saveCurso);

module.exports =  api;
```

I want to save the data with the name, description and in the image, i want to save the url from cloudinary.

I saved some images in cloudinary but I can't find the way to save only the url in my image field

NOTE: I'm using body-parser and this is my app.js

```
'use strict';

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const curso_routes = require('./routes/curso');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', curso_routes);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to handle the `multipart/form-data` using a package like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) or [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty). So, using multiparty :

```
'use strict';

const Curso = require('../models/curso');
const config = require('../config');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
const multiparty = require('multiparty');

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: 'something',
  api_key: 'somthingelse',
  api_secret: 'andotherthing'
})

function saveCurso(req, res) {

  //How to get the image and upload it to cloudinary
  let form = new multiparty.Form({ maxFilesSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 }); //setting max size of image to 10MB
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) return err
    let curso = new Curso();
    curso.name = fields.name;
    curso.description = fields.description;
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(files.content[0].path, (err, result) => { // content is the name of the image input on the front end form
      if (err) return err
      curso.image = result.secure_url;
      curso.save((err, cursoSaved) => {
        if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error' }); }
        if (!cursoSaved) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Empty' });
        return res.status(200).send({ curso: cursoSaved });
      });
    });
  }) 
}
```

Comment: you make a post request to `/api/curso` and the body is `form-data` and choose one of the inputs as file instead of text. according to the example above, the key would be 'content' and the value is the image.

Comment: in fact that I did but I only got error, I loged it and it was that my other field where required

Comment: Can you explain more? what error did you get? and what did you log ?

Comment: This: if (err) { console.log(err); return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error' }); }  to get a response in postman and see the error in console

And in my console i see: 
 ValidationError: Curso validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., description: Path `description` is required.

Comment: when you are trying in postman, are you sending the 'name' and the 'description' fields or only the image ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155947/discussion-between-m-sallam-and-supinedread89).

Answer (score 0):

with plain **HTML** **JavaScript**

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
const uploading_text = document.getElementById("uploading_text");

// replace with your data 
const cloud_name = "demo";
const upload_preset = "doc_codepen_example";
// replace with your data 

fileInput.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  uploading_text.innerText = "uploading...";
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);
  formData.append("upload_preset", upload_preset);
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  };

  return fetch(
    `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloud_name}/image/upload`,
    options
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      // url 
      console.log(data.secure_url);

      uploading_text.innerHTML = `
      <span>upload complete.</span>
      <br />
      <img style="max-width:300px" src="${data.secure_url}" alt="">
      <a href="${data.secure_url}">${data.secure_url}</a>
      `;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
    
<p id="uploading_text"></p>
```